# mysql query with lat lng and multiple search joins

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have mysql query like that it's working fine but i want to check where condition now branches.visible=1 then also show in the query

```
SELECT 
    company.name,
    company.id,
    company.mobile,
    company.telephone,
    IFNULL(fav.status, 'no') AS 'favorite',branchInfo.logo,
    ((((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((branches.lat*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((branches.lat*pi()/180)) * cos((($lng- branches.lng)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) AS 'distance',
    branchInfo.telephone,
    branchInfo.id,
    branchInfo.name,
    branches.buffet,
    branches.halal,
    branches.kidsPlayArea,
    branches.liveBand,
    branches.outdoor,
    branches.sheesha,
    branches.valetParking,
    branches.petsAllowed,
    branches.wiFi,
    branches.sportEvents,
    branches.reservationRequired,
    branches.wheelChairAccess,
    branches.acceptCreditCard,
    branches.brunch,
    branchInfo.name,
    branches.street,
    branches.city,
    branches.area,
    branches.lat,
    branches.lng,
    branches.id,
    branches.visible 
FROM branches
LEFT JOIN users branchInfo 
    ON branchInfo.id=branches.branchId 
LEFT JOIN users company 
    ON company.id=branches.companyId
LEFT JOIN favorite_branches fav 
    ON fav.branchId=branches.branchId AND fav.userId=$uId
HAVING distance < 25
```

Comment: You broke my eyes(

Comment: why i broke your eyes bro

Comment: Formatting your code to be readable is something to consider before posting. I've edited your post to make the code readable. Have you tried adding a where clause?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, _HAVING_ is generally used with _GROUP BY_, if there's no _GROUP BY_, use a 
_WHERE_ clause.

Comment: i tried it with where but it not working my above query working perfect but i also want to add branches.visible=1 now more in this query but its not working with this.

Comment: See my answer below. It uses a where clause and both of your conditions.

Comment: @SloanThrasher It's fine. It's just to avoid writing out the formula twice - although that approach is probably faster!

Answer (score 0):

Use a where clause and add your condition there:

```
SELECT 
    company.name,
    company.id,
    company.mobile,
    company.telephone,
    IFNULL(fav.status, 'no') AS 'favorite',branchInfo.logo,
    ((((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((branches.lat*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((branches.lat*pi()/180)) * cos((($lng- branches.lng)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) AS 'distance',
    branchInfo.telephone,
    branchInfo.id,
    branchInfo.name,
    branches.buffet,
    branches.halal,
    branches.kidsPlayArea,
    branches.liveBand,
    branches.outdoor,
    branches.sheesha,
    branches.valetParking,
    branches.petsAllowed,
    branches.wiFi,
    branches.sportEvents,
    branches.reservationRequired,
    branches.wheelChairAccess,
    branches.acceptCreditCard,
    branches.brunch,
    branchInfo.name,
    branches.street,
    branches.city,
    branches.area,
    branches.lat,
    branches.lng,
    branches.id,
    branches.visible 
FROM branches
LEFT JOIN users branchInfo 
    ON branchInfo.id=branches.branchId 
LEFT JOIN users company 
    ON company.id=branches.companyId
LEFT JOIN favorite_branches fav 
    ON fav.branchId=branches.branchId AND fav.userId=$uId
WHERE ((((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((branches.lat*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((branches.lat*pi()/180)) * cos((($lng- branches.lng)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) < 25 
AND branches.visible = 1
```

Comment: Good catch @Strawberry. I've updated the answer. Please consider changing your down-vote.